# php login system selecting database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a login system with php but I'm getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_select_db(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in
>       /home/a9356103/public_html/login.php on line 13

and the code is:

```
<?php
    $mysql_host = 'localhost';
    $mysql_database = 'a9356103_web';
    $mysql_user = 'a9356103_web';
    $mysql_password = 'password';

    if (isset($_REQUEST['attempt'])) {
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];

      $con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
      mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);
    }
?>
```

I'm new to php and the forms so any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Sidenote: Besides the fact that you're mixing SQL APIs, you're using plain text passwords; **don't**. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, *amongst a few*.

Comment: I can only assume your query will be subject to SQL injections.  Be sure to use prepared statements with `mysqli` or use `PDO`.  Do not directly call `$user` or `$pass` in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing mysqli and mysql functions:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password); <-- WRONG FUNCTION
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);
```

should be

```
$con=mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);
```

Actually, you should be using mysqli since [mysql is deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

```
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password, $mysql_database);
```

Comment: +1 I honestly don't know where people get the idea that they can mix APIs, *baffling*.

Comment: My best guess it is copy and paste from multiple sources/tutorials

Comment: It's even more baffling that the tutorial referenced `mysql_*` rather than `mysqli_*` or PDOs. I thought that `mysqli` came out so long ago that any tutorial on the first page of Google would use it.

Comment: The `mysql_*` tutorials are so old they have a *ton* of links to them. They will be tough to dislodge from the first page of the search results.

Comment: thanks soo much i think its fixed, ive been following a tut series to try and learn php because right now im a noob

Comment: @user3513321 We were all new once and we're all still learning. Good luck.